# How does the jmp instruction work in att assembly in this instance

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I am stepping through a function in AT&T assembly right now and can't figure out how this specific jmp command works.

```
    jmp    *0x804a140(,%eax,4)
```

How exactly is it using the %eax register and 4 with the jump instruction? I have never seen jmp used this way before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are confused by at&t syntax, switch your tool to intel mode.

The effective address you see is not specific to jumps, you could have encountered it with any instruction that takes a memory operand.

In intel syntax this would look like: `jmp [0x804a140 + 4 * eax]`. It's an indirect jump that  fetches the jump target from memory address `0x804a140 + 4 * eax`. This is probably an item in a so-called jump table.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense for the code. I just wasn't sure how that was read in AT&T syntax and searching online made it endlessly more confusing. Thanks!