# Jmp x86 explanation

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, att

I'm dealing with some x86 code and I know for the most part what the `jmp` command is used for and what it does, but this one line absolutely perplexes me.

```
jmp    *0x804a0e0(,%eax,4)
```

`eax` is dependent on earlier input and should be an int.  0x804a0e0 contains 60 (base 10). Can someone please explain what this is saying?

Comment: what's the raw instruction?

Comment: i don't know what you mean by raw

Comment: in gdb, disas with a /r modifier, raw instructions in hex are included.

Comment: The most confusing thing about this instruction is the weird AT&T syntax. In Intel syntax it would be simply `jmp [0x804a0e0 + eax * 4]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the jmp instruction work in att assembly in this instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418524/how-does-the-jmp-instruction-work-in-att-assembly-in-this-instance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `jmp    *0x804a0e0(,%eax,4)`

This instruction is quite simple: given an `array` of function pointers (the array starts at address `0x804a0e0`), and an index `i` (stored in `%eax`), call the function, a pointer to which is stored in `array[i]`.

You are most likely to encounter such instruction in C++ (virtual function calls are implemented this way).

Using `(gdb) info symbol 0x804a0e0` will tell you what global the `array` actually corresponds to.